# Cannot serve static file on expressjs for angular

Tags: html, css, angularjs, express

I'm unable to serve static file on express. Here is my code:

```
app.use("/#", express.static(__dirname + '../client/partials/javascripts'));
app.use( express.static(__dirname + '/../client/partials/stylesheets'));
app.use('/?#/', express.static(__dirname + '../client/partials/stylesheets'));
app.use('/?', express.static(__dirname + '../client/partials/stylesheets'));
app.use('/#', express.static(__dirname + '../client/partials/stylesheets'));
app.use('/style', express.static(__dirname + '../client/partials/stylesheets'));
app.use('http://localhost:3000/?#/', express.static(__dirname + '../client/partials/stylesheets'));
```

I checked the directory path and it's correct... Please help me guys...

Comment: What version of express are you using?

Comment: 10x for your reply am using "express": "^4.13.4",

Comment: Does your program give any errors when it runs, or when you try to access your static routes?

Comment: I now serve the css and angular files with this command :

    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../client/partials')));

but my angular doesnt work. help please

Comment: Sorry but I can be of no assistance when it comes to angular.